# Webpack/React dynamic image imports with require & context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Searching around...lots of suggestions but nothing feels "right".  I want to have a true dynamic CSS background image:

```
const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${props => props.img});
  width: 200px;
`;
```

using my react component, I want to **avoid** having a long list of `import img1 from "../../img1.jpg"; import img2 from "../../img2.jpg"` and so on (as example).

So I am trying to use `require.context(path)` to generate the number of items in the directory.  And I implement like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

import hdImg from "../../../public/assets/img/hd_bgimage.jpg";

// get the number of items in the directory
const imageKeys = require
  .context("../../../public/assets/img/bgs/", true)
  .keys();

function getBgImage(num) {
  const imageUrl = require(`../../../public/assets/img/bgs/${num}_bgimage.jpg`);
  return imageUrl;
}

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  background-image: url(${props => props.img});
  width: 200px;
`;

const StyledImg = styled.img`
  width: 200px;
`;

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <div id="container">
        {imageKeys.map((item, i) => (
// loop over items from context
          <StyledDiv id="image-bg" img={getBgImage(i + 1)} key={item}>
            this is a background image CSS
          </StyledDiv>
        ))}
      </div>
      <StyledImg id="img" src={hdImg}></StyledImg>
      <Link to="/link">Test Link</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

webpack.config.base:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: [path.join(__dirname, "./src/scripts")],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       // js removed
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
              name: "[name].[ext]",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

it's working out "fine" when rendered in UI:

[image]

but i don't love the code here.

If i try to use just `const imgContext = require.context("../../../public/assets/img/bgs/, true)`
and then reference `imgContext(i)` the relative path of `./1_bgimage.jpg)` doesn't get found so it seems like I *need* the full url including `../../../public/assets/img/bgs/`.

Is there something I am missing?

Is there something I can do with my webpack config to not have to declare `../../../public`??

Comment: You could use webpack "resolve alias" to specify the folder with your assets, therefore shorten the paths in your imports.